# Как здесь раставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста! Мне кажется, запятая перед "если" лишняя. Также не уверена насчет запятой перед "при"...

В последние годы отчетливо прослеживается следующая тенденция: рост рынка, если и происходит, то в основном за счет импорта и в стоимостном выражении, при сохранении неизменного натурального объема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая, конечно, не нужна. Последнюю я бы поставил.

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 0):

В придаточном предложении с частицами: и, же, даже ''если'' употребляется в значении уступительного союза. Запятая не требуется. Я жду если и не одобрения, то по крайней мере ободряющих слов. А вот вторая запятая действительно нужна, она закрывает вторую часть двойного союза: если ...то.